# Return "No Records Returned" on empty mysql query return

Tags: php

I have a php script that pulls information from a mysql table. I am wanting to display a message if the script returns no rows.

I have tried:

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

   if($numrows == 0)
   { 
      echo "No entries"; 
   } 
   else
   {
      //rest of code below 
   }
```

But it only returns an error that says:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/content/38/10473938/html/nhs_musical_blog/dashboard.php on line 211
```

I don't understand because I found this code on stack overflow.com and the asker was more than happy with this answer and it seemed to work just fine for him/her. What am I doing wrong to get poor results?

My full code: (minus login details)

```
                 <?php
                    // Check connection
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                      {
                      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                      }

                    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM date_entries");

                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

                    if($numrows == 0)
                    { 
                        echo "No entries"; 
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<ul class='mws-summary clearfix'>";

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                          {
                          echo "<li>";
                          echo "<span class='key'>" . $row['name'] . "</span>";
                          echo "<span class='val'><span class='text-nowrap'>" . $row['date'] . "<a href='' target='_blank'><i class='icon-chevron-right pull-right' style='padding-top:5px;'></i></a>" . "</span></span>";
                          echo "</li>";
                          }
                        echo "</ul>"; 

                        mysqli_close($con);
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: I realize this could be considered to be a duplicate question, but I am trying to figure out why the solutions to previous questions are not bringing a solution to my problem.

Comment: Are you using mysqli or mysql ?

Comment: Ok, so minus the fact I feel like a MASSIVE IDIOT now and should be sentenced back to college. I have a solution. that one letter `i` fixed all my problems. I will accept the first answer that came in as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code is using `MYSQLI` and not plain `MYSQL`, this function should be `MYSQLI` version

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

should be

```
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                ^
```

Comment: Wil accept this answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

If you using MySQLi then you have to use

```
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```